# Getting into an infinite loop in MATLAB function

Tags: matlab, infinite

I'm trying to plot a function on matlab that's defined such that:
Y=-100t ; 0>=t>=0.15
Y=-15  ; t>.15

I'm using the following code:

```
function [ Y ] = Gain( t )

for t=[0:0.01:0.15]

        Y=-100*t
end

for t=0.15:0.01:2
        Y=-15
end
plot (Gain)
```

but I'm going into an infinite loop!

Would someone please solve this problem for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you setting Y to -15 in a loop? Also, what are you expecting to hapen when you loop t from 0.15 to 2, with the step of 1? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Because I want to draw a plot that's equal to -15 between 0.15 and 2. and changing the loop step to 0.01 doesn't help anyways I've tried that.

Comment: Why is `t` a parameter?

Comment: @user3140090 Obviously, however it's not an input to the function, which promptly clobbers it as a variable.

Comment: Since you are already changing value inside the function, you are better off writing a MATLAB script instead of the function. You can do something like this - `Y=[-100.*(0:0.01:0.15) -15+0.*(0.15:0.01:2)]; plot(Y)`.

Answer (score 1):

Functions don't work like that in MATLAB, unfortunately. (Or at least I don't think they do). Try something like this:

```
function Y = Gain(t)
    Y = -100*t;
    Y(t >= 0.15) = -15;
end

x = 0:0.01:2;
plot(x, Gain(x))
```

MATLAB still uses C-esque functions, so you have to define it that way, using C-style syntax, instead of more math-like syntax, unfortunately. I'm multiplying the input values by -100, then for the ones that match up to where t is greater than 15, I replace those with -15. MATLAB is weird.

Edit: Sorry, previous code sample also used the wrong syntax.. MATLAB is weird.

Comment: what sort of variable t should be ? I tried Global but it's not working. I think this is why I'm having the error: Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Comment: Try the new code I posted. Sorry, it's been a while since I've used MATLAB.. Here it's assumed `t`'s either some sort of vector, matrix, or set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what you're TRYING to do, but when you call the `Gain` function "from outside", so to speak,...

1. You enter the `Gain` function
2. The first `for` loop executes, overwriting passed-in value of `t` with each iteration.  (Therefore, the value of `t` that you passed in is completely ignored, the way that you have this code written.)
3. The second for-loop executes, and
4. You call `plot(Gain)`, which forces `Gain` to be called again, this time with no arguments.  Back to 1.

Repeat forever.

Comment: +1, it sounds like the problem is a missing `end` before the last line.